# Facebook javascript users_getInfo getting email

Tags: javascript, api, facebook

How can I get the email address of a user from my app?

Right now I have it as

```
FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_getInfo(uid, 'last_name, first_name, email_hashes', userInfoCallback);
```

The `last_name` and `first_name` does work, but `email_hashes` gives an empty Object.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 3):

For the record, [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407109/facebook-javascript-users-getinfo-getting-email#answer-1407565) is no longer correct, you can query email (and proxied_email) these days if your app received email permission from the user:

```
FB.Facebook.apiClient.users_getInfo(uid,
                                    'last_name, first_name, email',
                                    userInfoCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you can't. The point of FB Connect is authentication without having to enter an email. You're using Facebook as a proxy to authenticate. From their docs:

> "Contact information (email address,
>   phone number) are not directly
>   available via the APIs."

You can use the javascript API to *send* emails to the user through Facebook however. You first have to using the [ShowPermissionDialog](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JS_API_M_FB.Connect.ShowPermissionDialog) method for the permission "email". This will give your application permission to contact the user. Then you can use the [Notifications.sendEmail](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.sendEmail) method.